# 20.04 lts, minicom file not supported

Tags: 20.04, minicom

When I download from here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/minicom/2.7.1-1.1

Ubuntu Software reports
**Failed to install file: unsupported**

Details

Package version:
2.7.1-1.1

Source:
minicom 2.7.1-1.1 source package in Ubuntu

Status:
Published

Component:
universe

Priority:
Optional

Downloadable files
amd64 build of minicom 2.7.1-1.1 in ubuntu focal PROPOSED produced these files:

**minicom_2.7.1-1.1_amd64.deb (233.0 KiB)**

Any other way get errors as well. No support for ARM64.  it worked on 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Minicom application using [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/minicom) from official repositories using commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

The arm64 is supported, you can find its *minicom_2.7.1-1.1_arm64.deb* file in http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/m/minicom/ .

Answer (score 0):

it did work.

```
buntu@ubuntu:~$ minicom
minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

It's not the response expected  `minicom -D /dev/tty`
Gave this :

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Dec 23 2019, 02:06:26.
Port /dev/tty, 18:41:04
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> for help on special keys

response.

**We're good now.**  Thanks.  It's much harder and hidden than in 12.04 LTS.  The entire Ubuntu Software Center needs to revert back to the 12.04 level of behavior.

Thanks.